# What is the probability of being hit given alarm has sounded? Bayesian Signal Detection

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Imagine you are a radar operator aboard a submarine and you have a sensor that alerts you of incoming torpedos. The sensor has a 90% hit rate (it goes off 90% of the times there is a torpedo coming). It has a 10% false alarm rate. You know that you are currently in friendly waters, so your subjective prior probability of being hit at any given moment is low: .05. In this situation, what is the probability of being hit given that the sensor goes off?

I solved this as: $$P(\text{Hit}\mid \text{Alarm}) = \frac {P(\text{Alarm}\mid \text{Hit}) \times P(\text{Hit})} {P(\text{Alarm})}$$
Which becomes: $$P(\text{Hit}\mid\text{Alarm}) = \frac {.9 \times .05} {.1} = .45$$

The issue I see is that when you raise the prior, the posterior can become $>1$ which confuses me. Thank you for your help, I am new to Bayes Theorem and probability generally so I apologize if this problem is too simple.

Comment: The probability that you hear the alarm has two pieces:  either there is no torpedo ($.95$) and you have a false positive ($.1$) or there is a torpedo ($.05$) and you have a true positive ($.9$).  Thus the probability that the alarm sounds is $.95\times .1 +.05\times .9$

Comment: Why do you substitute $.9$ in $P(\text{Alarm}\mid\text{Hit})$? You say $.9$ is the probability of being hit if the alarm goes off, so that should be $P(\text{Hit}\mid\text{Alarm})$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Darsen, I substituted .9 for P(Alarm | Hit) because given that a torpedo is really coming, the alarm will detect it 90% of the time. What we want to solve is this situation: given that the alarm goes off, what is the probability there really is a torpedo coming. I could be completely wrong in my approach / wording of this, I apologize for the confusion

Comment: Ok, I understand. So just to be clear, then the $.1$ is the probability of the alarm not going off when there's actually a torpedo coming, right?

Comment: Yes, .1 is both the probability of a miss (torpedo is coming but sensor doesn't alarm) and the probability of a false alarm (sensor goes off when there is no torpedo coming)